# (closed)How to use groupy by with subquery which join table?

Tags: sql

I have no idea how to `group by` by the column from subquery.

I want to group by `language`as below:

[image]

Here is my code:

```
select a.name, count(a.language) as count
from
    (select 
        temp2.name,
        countrylanguage.language
    from 
        countrylanguage
    right join  
        temp2
    on 
        temp2.code = countrylanguage.countrycode
    ) as a
group by a.language;
```

### Edited

I got a solution as below:

```
select temp2.name, count(countrylanguage.language) 
from countrylanguage 
join temp2 on temp2.code = countrylanguage.countrycode 
group by temp2.name;
```

Comment: . . The correct thing to do when you have an answer is to accept the best answer from those who proposed one.  Don't edit your question with the answer.  If there is no appropriate answer to accept (there is one in this case), then you can provide your own answer and accept that one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try below - you don't need any subquery

```
select temp2.name,count(countrylanguage.language)
  from countrylanguage join temp2
    on temp2.code = countrylanguage.countrycode
group by temp2.name
```

Comment: Thanks! I got a clue from your solution as below:```select temp2.name, count(countrylanguage.language)
from countrylanguage join temp2
on temp2.code = countrylanguage.countrycode
group by temp2.name;```

Answer (score 1):

Table data : 
SELECT * FROM countrylanguage

[image]

---

SELECT * FROM temp2

[image]

SELECT a.[Name], SUM(CASE WHEN a.[language] IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END)  language_count
FROM
(SELECT
    temp2.[Name],
    countrylanguage.[language]
FROM  temp2
LEFT JOIN countrylanguage ON temp2.code = countrylanguage.countrycode) a

### GROUP BY a.name

[image]